# Powershell - trimming/splitting an object to export-csv

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do a very simple task in powershell, I am trying to export a list of users from AD with certain properties. The problem is I need to trim the manager property to only include the name not the OUs etc. When I do this though I have to convert the object to a string which then I cant export to csv and cant get convertto-csv to work.

```
Get-ADUser gmclean  -Properties * | Select sapid,EmailAddress,GivenName,Surname,department,costcenter,Title,Office,MobilePhone,StreetAddress,City,State,PostalCode,Country,manager
```

sapid         : 111111
EmailAddress  : test@123.ca
GivenName     : Gray
Surname       : Mclean
department    : Edmonton Sales
costcenter    : 213456
Title         : Account manager
Office        : EDM
MobilePhone   : 123456789
StreetAddress : 123 street sw
City          : Edmonton
State         : AB
PostalCode    : Z2Z Z2Z
Country       : CA
manager       : CN=Tea Ping,OU=Users,OU=EDM,OU=CA,OU=Countries,DC=test,DC=testinc,DC=ca

In this I am able trim the manager property and combine the variables. But I cant figure out how to make headers for all the properties.

```
$Everything = Get-ADUser gmclean  -Properties * | Select sapid,EmailAddress,GivenName,Surname,department,costcenter,Title,Office,MobilePhone,StreetAddress,City,State,PostalCode,Country | ForEach-Object {$_.sapid,$_.EmailAddress,$_.GivenName,$_.Surname,$_.department,$_.costcenter,$_.Title,$_.Office,$_.MobilePhone,$_.StreetAddress,$_.City,$_.State,$_.PostalCode,$_.Country} | Out-string
$manager = Get-ADUser gmclean -Properties * | Select -Property manager | Out-string
$manager1 = $manager.split("="",")
$manager2 = $manager1[1]
$Everything1 = $Everything+$manager2
$Everything1
```

111111
test@123.ca
Gray
Mclean
Edmonton Sales
213456
Account manager
EDM
123456789
123 street sw
Edmonton
AB
Z2Z Z2Z
CA
Tea Ping

I am sure there is an easier way to do this but unfortunately I cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1) on your first pass through `Select` (all the way at the end):

```
Get-ADUser gmclean  -Properties * | Select sapid,EmailAddress,GivenName,Surname,department,costcenter,Title,Office,MobilePhone,StreetAddress,City,State,PostalCode,Country,@{Name='manager';Expression={$_.manager.Split("=,")[2]}}
```

Comment: What defines it as being a calculated property expression?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala The defining characteristic here is that `Select-Object` (and a few other cmdlets) natively accept a dictionary in the form `@{Name='...';Expression={...}}` (or with a `Label` entry in place of `Name`), in place of a plain parameter name. We call these property definitions ["calculated properties"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties). It's the scriptblock passed as the `Expression` value I'm referring to as a "calculated property expression"

Comment: Ahhh, I assumed so just wanted to make sure. Thank you.